# printing variable values using lmfit

Tags: python, optimization, lmfit

am trying to print variable values from lmfit minimization algorithm.am using `lmfit.printfuncs.report_fit(res.params)` am getting

```
[[Variables]]
    a:   123 (init= 123)
    b:   456 (init= 456)
    c:   789 (init= 789)
    d:   012 (init= 012)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are <  0.100)
```

Can i print just the outcome values like

```
123
456
789
012
```

Comment: Can you post  the code for your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result.params` is an ordered dictionary of Parameter objects, each of which has the best value stored in the `value` attribute, and several other attributes.  Basically, `fit_report` does something like:

```
for param in result.params.values():
    print("%s:  %f +/- %f (init = %f)" % (param.name, param.value, param.stderr, param.init_value)
```

You can modify that any way you'd like.

Comment: your answers works very well for me,and thank you so much for lmfit.its a great work all together am an active user of lmfit. :)

Answer (score 0):

am able to get variable values using `print(result.values)` if anyone can get the exact output,please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Specific values can be accessed by using

```
result.params.get('variable_name').value
```

For example:

```
result.params.get('fwhm').value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val_a = result.params.get['a'].value
print(val_a)
```

This is what I use, it works pretty well.